# Finding the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt\frac{x^2+6}{x-4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given $f(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+6}{x-4}}$, find the domain for the function $f(x)$.

My attempt failed:

So the first constraint is $\frac{x^2+6}{x-4}\geq0$ because of the radical.

Now, multiplying both sides by $x-4$ I get $x^2+6\geq0, x\neq4$.

And now $x^2\geq-6$, so $x\in\mathbb{R}-\{4\}$

But if I were to plug in say 3 for x I encounter a problem because in this case I get $\frac{x^2+6}{x-4}\lt0$

Comment: you cannot multiply both sides by $x-4$ as we dont know the sign of x-4

Comment: I will not write never $x^2\geq-6$ because $x^2+6>0, \forall x\in\Bbb R$ and never to solve an inequality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x^{2}+6 >0$ for all $x$ so $\frac {x^{2}+6} {x-4}$ exists and is $ \geq 0$ iff $x>4$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the numerator is always non negative, the fraction is non negative only if the denominator is non negative. So x can't be less than 4. Beside, since the fraction with zero denominator is undefined, x can't be 4. So x>4.

Comment: If $x = 4$, then the fraction is undefined, so we require that $x > 4$.

Comment: You are right, thank you. She'll I correct my answer?

Comment: You should correct your answer.

Comment: I did. Thank you again.